# mySQL query for multiple attributes

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to run this query to match all of these numbers without running the query 5 times? and if this is possible, how do I query these numbers if they're in a php array?

Numbers: 1, 26, 44, 45, 13

Query String:

```
SELECT ky, project_name FROM project WHERE ky = 1 OR 26 OR 44 OR 45 OR 13;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways

```
/* ... */ WHERE ky = 1 OR ky = 26 OR /* ... */
```

Or you could use `IN`

```
/* ... */ WHERE ky IN (1, 26, /* etc */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IN keyword which is equallent to ORs

```
SELECT ky, project_name FROM project WHERE ky IN ( 1, 26, 44, 45, 13);
```